# React native- How to display one time splash video in react native?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, hybrid

I am creating a project where I have a one time splash video screen, which is used for display some intro video of the application.after the video, app needs to load sign in screen which is already created.have no problem with that but don't have any clue how to do one time splash screen.

your help is highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Can you post what did you tried ? It depends on how your navigation is. For example with flux navigation you can do that with NavigationActions.login()

Comment: You can  set an application property , which will delete when application  uninstalling

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply I tried this tutorial and its not working.https://medium.com/technoetics/creating-first-time-user-welcome-screen-in-react-native-42f08cb0ebbe

Answer (score 2):

I haven't dealt with video in React Native before so I am unfamiliar with its capabilities handling video, but just googling react native video returns the [react-native-video library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) which has an onEnd prop. Like Anis D said, it would depend on your navigation and how you are storing your data, but if it were me using react-navigation for my navigation, I would have a component that is rendered on app startup that checks if they have viewed the video, returning the component to display the video if not, otherwise returning the main application stack if so. Something like below

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
     if (!this.props.hasViewedVideo) {
        return <MyVideoComponent/>
     }
     return <MainApplicationStack/>
  }
}
```

And in the MyVideoComponent that renders the video player, on the onEnd prop, set the hasViewedVideo variable to true. If you need to show the video only once per install, I would suggest looking into redux and redux persist to store this data. Otherwise, if the video needs to be shown every time the app is started up, using state inside the initial component would be fine, which would look more like below

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hasViewedVideo: false
  }

  render() {
     if (!this.state.hasViewedVideo) {
        return <MyVideoComponent/>
     }
     return <MainApplicationStack/>
  }
}
```

With async storage, might look something like this

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hasViewedVideo: false 
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const hasViewedVideo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hasViewedVideo')
    this.setState({ hasViewedVideo })
  }

  onVideoEnd = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('hasViewedVideo', true)
    this.setState({ hasViewedVideo: true})
  }

  render() {
     if (!this.state.hasViewedVideo) {
        return <MyVideoComponent onVideoEnd={this.onVideoEnd}/>
     }
     return <MainApplicationStack/>
  }
}
```

Which passes the onVideoEnd prop into the child MyVideoComponent component, and uses it in the onEnd prop of the video player.

Comment: brother do have any thing in mind how to do this using AsyncStorage?

Comment: added an example of how you might do that